# How to display stored locations from a database on a map?

Tags: android, phpmyadmin, latitude-longitude, android-maps-v2

I want to build an app which will display restaurants stored in a database (name, lat, long etc...) on a map within certain radius from the user. The user can then click on a particular restaurant to view more information or add a review about that restaurant. I know how to fetch the name of restaurants from the database using JSON and PHP and display them in a list view. But I want to be able to display them on a map. Could someone please point me in the correct direction on how to get this done?

Comment: Please post your efforts for SO members to help you better.

Comment: See this project on [Github](https://github.com/NeilSayok/Car-Locator-System). It does something like you say. It Locates car instead of restruants.

Comment: @SayokMajumder sir, can you please share .sql file.

Comment: @AbhilashKaranth I don't have any specific sql files for the project. The database are hosted online and details are put inside webfiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this.. it will show the marker for that location

       MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
       LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);  // latitude and longitude
       mp.position(newLatLng);
       mp.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.your_icon));
       mp.title("Title");
       mp.snippet(location); // location 
       googleMap.addMarker(mp);
```

Comment: sir, latitude and longitude of that location should be reflected from mysql database. Suppose a restaurant registered with us and we have to show their details if it is nearer to user while he is searching.  I am looking for this kind of code

Comment: Okay Sir, You have list of restaurants details with location in your db. if user going to search restaurant means at the time you can the get current location of the user. Now calculate the distance with restaurant  locations, filter out the restaurant  list send to app. app will show all the  restaurants on map.

Comment: yes sir, i am trying to find out solution for above task. But still didn't get the desired output